# calculating the $P(X,Y,Z) , P(X,Z)$ and $P(X|Y,Z)$ when Z=X+Y

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent binary random variable with the same alphabet {$0,1$},ie,$Pr(0)=Pr(1)=\frac{1}{2}$

I have known the probability of P(X|Z) already.

```
X    Y   X+Y  X⊕Y  Prob
0    0    0    0    1/4 
0    1    1    1    1/4
1    0    1    1    1/4
1    1    2    0    1/4
```

For $\mathbb P(X=x \mid Z=z)$

- $\mathbb P(X=0 \mid X+Y=0)=1$, $\,\mathbb P(X=1 \mid X+Y=0)=0$,
- $\mathbb P(X=0 \mid X+Y=1)=\frac12$, $\mathbb P(X=1 \mid X+Y=1)=\frac12$,
- $\mathbb P(X=0 \mid X+Y=2)=0$, $\,\mathbb P(X=1 \mid X+Y=1)=1$

But i don't know how to calculate the $P(X,Y,Z) , P(X,Z)$ and $P(X|Y,Z)$? Is $P(X,Y,Z)=P(X,Z)$? Is $P(X|Y,Z)=P(X|Z)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X \perp Y$ then $P(X,Y) = P(X) \, P(Y) = 1/4$.

$$
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  p_{XY}& 0 & 1 & p_Y  \\
  0 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/2\\
  1 &  1/4 & 1/4 & 1/2\\
  \hline
  p_X & 1/2& 1/2 & 1
\end{array}
$$

Let’s construct the table of the marginals to find $P(X=x,Z=z) = p_{XZ}(x,z)$.

$$
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  p_{XZ}& 0 & 1 & p_Z  \\
  0 & ?  & 0  & ?\\
  1 &  ? & ?  & ?\\
  2 & 0 & ? & ? \\
  \hline
  p_X & 1/2& 1/2 & 1
\end{array}
$$

Observe that $p_Z(0) = p_{XY}(0,0) = 1/4$ as $Z = 0 \iff X = 0 \cap Y = 0$. The same holds for $p_Z(2) = p_{XY}(1,1) = 1/4$. Then $p_Z(1) = 1 - 1/4 - 1/4 = 1/2$.

$$
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  p_{XZ}& 0 & 1 & p_Z  \\
  0 & ?  & 0  & 1/4\\
  1 &  ? & ?  & 1/2\\
  2 & 0 & ? & 1/4 \\
  \hline
  p_X & 1/2& 1/2 & 1
\end{array}
$$

It is easy to resolve all the $?$ inside the table.

$$
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  p_{XZ}& 0 & 1 & p_Z  \\
  0 & 1/4  & 0  & 1/4\\
  1 &  1/4 & 1/4  & 1/2\\
  2 & 0 & 1/4 & 1/4 \\
  \hline
  p_X & 1/2& 1/2 & 1
\end{array}
$$

Note that $p_{XZ} = p_{YZ}$.

Note also that $p_{XY}(x,y) = p_{XYZ}(x,y,0)+p_{XYZ}(x,y,1)+p_{XYZ}(x,y,2)$, then:
\[
\begin{align}
p_{XY}(0,0) = p_{XYZ}(0,0,0) = 1/4 \\
p_{XY}(0,1) = p_{XYZ}(0,1,1) = 1/4 \\
p_{XY}(1,0) = p_{XYZ}(1,0,1) = 1/4 \\
p_{XY}(1,1) = p_{XYZ}(1,1,2) = 1/4 \\
\end{align}
\]

---

**Supplement** - The conditional mutual information $I(X,Y|Z)$ can be calculated using the formula shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mutual_information).

$$I(X,Y|Z)=\sum_{z\in Z}\sum_{y\in Y}\sum_{x\in X}p_{XYZ}(x,y,z)\log\frac{p_Z(z)p_{XYZ}(x,y,z)}{p_{XZ}(x,z)p_{YZ}(y,z)}$$
Then 
\[
\begin{align}
I(X,Y|Z) &= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{z\in Z}\sum_{y\in Y}\sum_{x\in X}\log\frac{1\,/\,4\cdot p_Z(z)}{1\,/\,4 \cdot 1\,/\,4} \\
&= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{z\in Z}\sum_{y\in Y}\sum_{x\in X}\log\left(4 \, p_Z(z)\right) \\
&= \sum_{z\in Z}\log\left(4 \, p_Z(z)\right) & \left[\text{$\sum_y\sum_x f(z)=4f(z)$}\right] \\
&= \log\frac{4}{4} + \log\frac{4}{2} + \log\frac{4}{4} \\
&= \log 2
\end{align}
\]
If $\log = \log_2$ then
\[I(X,Y|Z)= 1 \text{ bit}\]

Comment: but if $I(X;Y|Z)=H(X|Z)-H(X|Y,Z)=[\frac{-1}{4}log_21+0+\frac{-1}{4}log_2\frac{1}{2}+\frac{-1}{4}log_2\frac{1}{2}]-[\frac{1}{4}log_2\frac{1}{4} \times 4]=\frac{1}{2} -2=$ 
  negative value,but the I(X;Y|Z) should be semipositive ,$\gt$.

Comment: @ShineSun just edited the answer to calculate what you requested. I'm going to investigate your formula right now.

Comment: may i ask why is $I(X,Y|Z)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{z\in Z}\sum_{y\in Y}\sum_{x\in X}\log\frac{1/8}{[p_{X|Z}(x,z)]^2} 
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{z\in Z}\sum_{x\in X}\log\frac{1/8}{[p_{X|Z}(x,z)]^2}$ ?Why is $\sum_y=2$

Comment: I think I did something wrong there, from another calculation it comes out $I(X,Y|Z)=2+2-2-1.5=0.5 \text{ bits}$. I'm going to figure out that and improve comments ASAP

Comment: It's a bit embarassing, I made a mistake while copying the formula from Wikipedia. Moreover now I get $I(X,Y|Z)=1 \text{ bit}$ from the corrected version. I'm afraid the assumption $P(X|Y,Z)=P(X,Z)$ is wrong and I also misused a formula in the calculation I cited in my previous comment.. I've updated the answer in the meanwhile.